# TypeError: 'Circle' object does not support indexing

Tags: python, animation

I'm working on a python code to simulate orbital motion for any given system. I'm using FuncAnimation in order to animate the position of some circles. The thing is that I'm trying to make it as general as possible, so I thought that an array with the different patches, that I update at every frame, would be a good idea. But I'm getting this error every time that I run it:`TypeError: 'Circle' object does not support indexing`

Here is the part of the code for the animation:

```
# This class method is the core of the animation and how the different CelestialBodies interact.
def Animation(self,a):
    for u in range(len(self.system)-1):
        self.system[u].Position(self.system)
        self.patches[u].center = (self.system[u].P[-1][0],self.system[u].P[-1][1])
    return self.patches

# This is the main class method, which combines the rest of methods to run the animation.
def run(self):
    # Create the axes for the animation
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = plt.axes()
    ax.axis('scaled')
    ax.set_xlim(-self.max, self.max)
    ax.set_ylim(-self.max, self.max)

    # Create the patches and add them to the axes
    self.patches = []
    for q in range(len(self.system)-1):
        self.patches.append(plt.Circle(plt.Circle((0,0), 695700000, color='black')))
        ax.add_patch(self.patches[q])
    # Call the animation and display the plot
    anim = FuncAnimation(fig, self.Animation, init_func=self.init, frames=10, repeat=True, interval=1, blit=False)
    plt.title("Solar System - Numerical Intregation Simulation")
    plt.xlabel("Position in x (m)")
    plt.ylabel("Position in y (m)")
    plt.grid()
    plt.show()
# Constructor for the animation
def init(self):
    return self.patches
```

The entire Traceback is the following one:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "SolarSystem4.py", line 145, in <module> SolarSystem.run()
  File "SolarSystem4.py", line 132, in run ax.add_patch(self.patches[q])
  File      "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/matplotlib/axes.py", line 1562, in add_patch
self._update_patch_limits(p)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/matplotlib/axes.py", line 1580, in _update_patch_limits
xys = patch.get_patch_transform().transform(vertices)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/matplotlib/patches.py", line 1256, in get_patch_transform
self._recompute_transform()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/matplotlib/patches.py", line 1240, in _recompute_transform
center = (self.convert_xunits(self.center[0]),
TypeError: 'Circle' object does not support indexing
```

Comment: Please post the whole traceback.

Comment: Now you have it. Thank you and sorry about that :)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the problem lies in the first line inside the for loop in your `run` function.  here:

```
self.patches.append(plt.Circle(plt.Circle((0,0), 695700000, color='black')))
```

You are constructing a `Circle` object and then passing that object as the first argument to the constructor of another `Circle` object.  The first argument to the `Circle.__init__` is the `xy` coordinates of the circles centre. So when you are creating the second `Circle` it is expecting a tuple of the form `(x,y)` as that first argument, but instead is getting a whole `Circle` object instead and so it ends up with an attribute like:

```
self.center = Circle(....)
```

instead of

```
self.center = (0,0)  # or some other coordinates
```

This doesn't cause any problems until the `_recompute_transform` method is called which tries to index that `self.center` attribute.  Indexing a tuple is no problem but it can't index a `Circle` so it throws an error.  To fix, change the problematic line to:

```
self.patches.append(plt.Circle((0,0), 695700000, color='black'))
```

In other words, only make one `Circle` at a time and give its `__init__` method the arguments it expects.